# Trying to expand nested List of Dictionaries in Column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nested

I am trying to expand the column "Records" in my dataframe that is a nested list of dictionaries
I am trying to extract the columns:
Product, interest, Id, Company, Deal, Date, Family,Amount, Currency

```
 Size                      Records.id


 10    [{u'Product': u'Ops', u'interest': 
      None, u'Id': u'78827dhdgsg', u'Company': u'Panda', 
      u'attributes': {u'type': u'Lead', u'url': 
      u'x567'}, 
      u'Deal': u'xxx6787', u'Date': 
      u'2018-12-03', u'Family': u'Ops', 
      u'Amount': 9300, u'Currency': u'USD'}]

         [{u'Product': u'gold', 
  5    u'interest': None, u'Id': u'377ffh38', 
      u'Company': u'BIGPT', u'attributes': {u'type': u'Lead', u'url': 
      u'x57589'}, 
      u'Deal': u'wakft', u'Date': 
      u'2015-10-17', u'Family': u'bugs', 
      u'Amount': 48889, u'Currency': u'USD'}]
```

I've tried

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data['Records.id']],keys=data.index).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
```

This used to work but for some reason I keep getting error, ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

```
Size Product Interest Id   Company  Deal  Date     Family  Amount Currency

10   Ops             7882.. Panda xxx.. 2018-12-03   Ops     9300  USD 
5    Ops             377ff..BIGPT wakft 2015-10-17   Bugs   48889  USD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack`

```
df_1 = (df.set_index('Size')['Records.id']
          .apply(pd.Series).stack()
          .apply(pd.Series).reset_index().drop('level_1',1))
```

You can also do this

```
df_2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['records id']], 
        keys=df['size']).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

But you need to join the `size` column to this `df_2` to get the final desired output dataframe.

Comment: I'm still getting ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: when I try df_2 = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['records id'][0], axis=1, 
           keys=(1, 2)).stack(0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)), i only get two rows of data

Comment: I think you are providing a string representation of a dict to the DataFrame constructor, and not a dict itself. Try this `df = DataFrame(eval(data))` and then perform expand your dataframe.

Comment: i get this error TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

Comment: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['records id'][0:200]], keys=df.index).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index() when i try this it works, but i want the original columns of the dataframe also.

Comment: `df_2['records'] = df['records id'].reset_index().drop('index',1)` get the `records id` column from the main dataframe and join to this dataframe.